# Reishis Chochmah on Images

Tags: sources-mekorot

Someone sent me a quote from the Reishis Chochmah which states:

*"Everything that a person looks at, the image penetrates and fixes itself in his mind, and when he comes to pray or to study Torah, those material images appear in his mind, and they damage and invalidate his thoughts, and he will not be able to concentrate as required, because the eyes only see through the power that resides in the soul and the soul receives those images that come through the eyes and if the person looks at nakedness, he causes nakedness to penetrate in a high place."*

I'm trying to find this quote in the original Sefer. Does anyone know where this can be found in the Reishis Chochmah?

Comment: How do you know RC says that exact quote??

Comment: Its in Sha'ar HaKedusha 8:16

Comment: @YK: Thank you very much! Do you happen to know the  Reishis Chochmah by heart?

Comment: @RealTorah No, My RC happens to come with a very well made index in the third chelek. Your quote is not exact, but its close enough to see that's what you meant.

Comment: @YK: What is the exact quote then?

Comment: @RealTorah It can be found here http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34973&st=&pgnum=268 10 lines down from the top starting from "ודע כי לתיקון המחשבה"

Comment: I updated your question to show you an example how to easily turn it into a better question. As you may have guessed from some of the comments, the way the question was originally formatted assumed a lot. In addition, any information you can add to the question may help other people find an answer for you. In this question, it looks like you pasted a quote you found somewhere. Linking to that quote (if it was online) or mentioning where you found the quote would be helpful and raise the quality of the question.

Comment: See also this for some more examples how to improve question quality: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/i-dont-think-were-explaining-sourcing-properly-to-new-users . By the way, don't feel obligated to keep my edit, you can edit it yourself to clarify and improve the question quality any way you want